# formatting a .txt file in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, file-io, data-science

I would like to take a .txt file that is in the following format:

```
StateOne[edit]

RegionOne (UniversityOne)[1]

RegionTwo (UniversityTwo)

RegionThree (UniversityThree)[2]
```

and have this data be cleaned up and returned in a DataFrame of this format:

```
State   RegionName
0   StateOne    RegionOne
1   StateOne    RegionTwo
2   StateOne    RegionThree
```

so for example I have:

```
Alabama[edit]

Auburn (Auburn University)[1]

Florence (University of North Alabama)

Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
```

and i need to convert this into the data frame:

```
    State   RegionName
0   Alabama Auburn
1   Alabama Florence
2   Alabama Jacksonville
```

I'm a bit confused how to remove characters like `"["` to the end and have them be named `"State"`. And for `"RegionName"`, when removing every character from `"("` to end when needed. Pretty new at pandas and confused about a quick easy way to do this.

Comment: generally it helps to get answers if you have at least tried, and show that

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm new to stack overflow so i'm learning the rules here. I tried a `str.split()` method but it didn't seem to get the results i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that the state always have the "edit" with `[]` and the regions `()`.

The trick is to do a [split](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) in "[" and "(" (as appropriate) and staying with the first part of the string.

```
string = '''Alabama[edit]

Auburn (Auburn University)[1]

Florence (University of North Alabama)

Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]'''

i = 0
print(' \t' + 'State' + '\t' + 'RegionName')

for line in string.split('\n'):       # Split by the line breaks
    if line == '':                    # We skip the line if it is empty
        continue
    if 'edit' in line:                # We look for some "edit" and 
        state, spam = line.split('[') # store it in a variable
        continue                      # When we find other
                                      # it will replace
    region_name, spam = line.split(' (')
    i += 1                            # The same but with '('
    print(str(i) + '\t' + state + '\t' + region_name)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.